# Yes/NO :Is this $f$ is convex?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $f(x)= \begin{cases} x^2  \text{ if }  x \in [0,1) , \\ 3 \  \text{if x=1} \end{cases}$

Is  this  $f$ is  convex  ?

My attempt : I thinks its  $f$ will not convex because  $f$ is not continious

Isits true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like these are exercises in careful readings of definitions. Note that the definition of convexity is

> In mathematics, a real-valued function is called convex (or convex downward or concave upward) if the line segment between any two points on the graph of the function lies above or on the graph.

And a line segment from $(a,f(a))\to(b,f(b))$ defined by $(p_t,q_t) = (a+t(b-a),f(a)+t(f(b)-f(a)))$ for $t\in[0,1]$ is above the function if for all $t\in[0,1]$, $q_t\geq f(p_t)$.

Can you use these definitions to finish the proof?

Answer (score 2):

Are all the chords on the same side of the graph?

I suggest a search for *does convex imply continuous*.